# Unable to install Ubuntu (20.04.02 or 21.04) on brand new HP Pavilion TP01 Desktop

Tags: boot, hp, usb-installation

I have this machine since a little more than a week and am working on it to install Ubuntu. Any recent version of Ubuntu will do (tried 20.04 and 21.04), single or dual boot doesn't matter much.

I boot it up with a USB "Startup Disk", ensure that the machine boots from that drive and get into grub.
The first strange thing is that there's no "try Ubuntu" option...
But when I select "install Ubuntu" (with or without safe mode), it either stops working (black screen), or switches over to the "HP logo - Ubuntu logo underneath and whirling arrows in the middle" screen. The arrows will rotate for a few minutes, then stop.

The PC: i7 11th Gen - 16 GB 1256 GB HDD+SSD - Windows 10 - Intel UHD Graphics

I have tried a lot of things, mostly found on Ask Ubuntu or Ubuntu Forums, mainly:

1. completely removing "secure mode" in the bios
2. switching SATA from RAID to AHCI

No change.

In desperation, I even tried to exchange the SSD-dive from that PC to my own (another HP, but just a bit older) to install Ubuntu there and switch it back again. I didn't succeed in unscrewing the SSD-cards fastener...

I *really* need this thing to work, as I finally managed to convince the company I work for to try Ubuntu...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried two different USB sticks...

Comment: Silly question, but have you verified the `.iso` file you downloaded as being accurate? There are occasions when an incomplete image is written to a USB, is bootable, but unable to install (because the installer detects the inconsistency) 

Comment: The question is far from silly... As a matter of fact, I was able to boot with a startup disk with Ubuntu 18.04. I'll try again with a verified 20.04.02 Right now! Thanks for this.

Comment: (I managed to install and get it to boot into U18.04, but after login I only get a blank screen with the mouse cursor). 

So, I just downloaded a new version of the Ubuntu 20.04.02 version iso file along with the checksum keys and checked the download: OK.
Just for curiosity's sake, I checked the version I used previously and... it's OK also.
I just made a new startup disk and will try asap...
Thanks for your hint!

Comment: The 11th Gen Intel CPUs are far too new for 18.04. I would probably go with 21.04 for such a new device (I use 21.04 on my 7th Gen i5, which is rock solid), but 20.04 *may* support it now that it has a newer kernel.

Comment: Thanks for that hint too! (can you tell I'm getting desperate?) ;)
The thing is, I cannot get any OTHER startup disk to work. I just tried again with the 20.04.02 (checked for errors) and... nada. 
No "try Ubuntu" option (has it disappeared?), only "install ubuntu". And when I try that, it gets stuck doing nothing.
I'm not an expert, but I have installed Ubuntu on about 30 computers previously without almost any hitch. Trying again with 21.04...

Comment: Verified BIOS and UEFI settings, tried a new (checked) 21.04 startup disk.
Stuck (again) at the boot screen (HP, swirling arrows and Ubuntu logo) for hours.
There IS something that seems to prevent Ubuntu from starting up.
(By the way, is it normal that there's no more "test Ubuntu" line in Grub?)

Comment: You should be booting into a live session. From there you’ll have the option to install the OS with an icon on the desktop. When the boot screen is visible are you able to hit [Esc] and see boot log messages? I’ve worked with fleets of HP notebooks and, so long as they’re not cheapo or “boutique” devices, they usually boot just fine. HP has a long history of Ubuntu support 

Comment: @RenéBartholemy I am facing the exact same problem. Have you come up with any solution?

Comment: try setting acpi=off in the grub menu
https://www.reddit.com/r/Hewlett_Packard/comments/pbg07d/cant_use_linux_on_my_new_hp_desktop/